# Template argument deduction for variadic char lists

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a struct

```
template<char...> struct foo {};
```

and a variadic function

```
template<char... chars> auto make_foo(char...) {
    return foo<chars...>();
}
```

However, I'm having trouble finding the correct syntax to get chars deduced automatically. As written, clang gives me

```
decltype(make_foo('a','b','c')) == foo<>
```

Instead, I would like to have

```
decltype(make_foo('a','b','c')) == foo<'a','b','c'>
```

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote?

Comment: For the record `auto make_foo(char...)` is the same as `auto make_foo(char, ...)`. That is a different kind of ellipsis than the one involved in variadic packs.

Comment: Benno, I did not downvote.  But your question reads like someone who barely understands template functions trying to use variardic value pack parameterized types: as they are new to the language, there is the assumption they are advanced, and your lack of understanding of basic template function code might be taken as wasting readers time.  Imagine someone who cannot `"hello world"` asking about multi threaded image processing code, where there problem is they called their main function `errcode MAIN(parameters)`.

Comment: In short, remove all `...` from your code.  (just the `...` -- leave stuff adjacent to `...` alone)  Pass `'a'`.  See what goes wrong?  Your problem is unrelated to varargs, other than varargs hiding the error somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

What it comes down to is you can't have such a `make_foo` *function* because it's parameters are all *runtime values*, which can't be converted to a *compile time values*.

However, you *can* simply use a macro.

```
#define make_foo(...) foo<__VA_ARGS__>{}
```